# c# check if thread/background task has finished or needs aborting

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I have a fairly simple requirement for my console/windows service (I can run it either mode) application:

1. Get a list of items to work on from the database
2. Start a method in the background (only one, never a need for more) to process one item
3. Check it has finished or needs terminating (via a sql lookup)
4. Repeat 2 when finished/aborted for the next
5. When no more,  sleep a little and repeat 1

I'm fairly new to c#/.net and there are various threading systems I can see. Which is better for this case, a thread or a task?

In the case of a thread I assume it's something like (this rough code) for each item to process:

```
Thread thread = new MyThread(new ThreadStart(this.SomeFunction));
thread.Start();
while(!finished) {
  if (!thread.IsAlive())
    finished=true; 
  else {
     //check database for early termination of job
     terminate=SomeChdck();
     if(terminate) { thread.Abort(); finished=true;}

  }
}
```

//return back and repeat

or in the case of Task it's something like (again, roughly done, and pinched from the web):

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.SomeFunction, token);
while(!finished) {
  if (task.IsCompleted)
    finished=true;
  else {
     //check database for early termination of job
     terminate=SoneChdck();
     if(terminate) { tokenSource.Cancel(); finished=true;}
  }
}
```

//return back and repeat

Is there a difference in the approach of these (assuming they will both work that is), and I read somewhere that Thread.Abort() was deprecated but there's no mention at the documentation.

thanks.

Comment: I would go with tasks (they're part of the Task Parallel Library aka TPL). They're newer, have less overhead (creating threads is costly), and overall more support and documentation. Here's a link to someone who had a pretty similar situation to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601182/recommended-usage-of-tpl-for-very-long-living-threads

Comment: By far the most important question you need to ask yourself is if you *need* a thread to get the job done.  Very important because it is so difficult to write and debug such code.  From what you posted, the answer to that question ought to be "no".

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort()` is bad - read this: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Answer (score 2):

This is generically called a Producer/Consumer problem.  You have one thread (your main thread) that is going to Produce a number of items for your background thread (Consumer) to pick up and work on.

The BlockingCollection in .net's Task Parallel Library can be useful for this.  Have a look at this article:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx

Also, I would recommend that you check out the Pipeline from Parallel Extensions Extras item that Darek suggested in his post.

And in general, I would recommend Tasks or the ThreadPool (in that order) over manually newing up a thread.  The threadpool is designed to reduce the overhead of constructing many threads by pooling them.    Tasks use the Threadpool.  It should be very rare that you need to manually create a Thread.

Comment: Here is a nice simple example from the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use Task Factory. You can wait on a task to complete using:

```
Task.WaitAll(task);
```

instead of the while loop in your sample code.

Also, the CancelationToken is used to signal to a task that it should cancel, so you need to perform checks yourself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/vstudio/dd997396(v=vs.100).aspx

However, you will be better off if you consider [Pipeline from Parallel Extensions Extras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/14/9995613.aspx), which also supports cancellation token. This way, you can retrieve records from DB, than pass them as IEnumerable to a pipeline, while you are free to cancel them all from a separate or internal thread. You can start processing with the first record, while the rest is retrieved in a background. Pipeline will create a background task for each of its steps for each of its elements to process. Default degree of parallelism is 1 for each step. It's extremely fast and efficient.

**UPDATE**

Small example with Dapper, Parallel Extensions Extras and Reactive Extensions

```
var pipeline = Pipeline.Create<SomeType, bool>(st =>
{
    //Do something with st
    return someBool; //some bool if you succeeded or not
});
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
//cancel after 10s (just for fun)
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Subscribe(s => cts.Cancel());
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("someConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    pipeline.Process(conn.Query<SomeType>("SOME SQL HERE", buffered:true),cts.Token).ToList();
}
```

The reason for this selection is to demonstrate how easy it is to employ Dapper, how powerful and convenient Parallel Extensions Extras are, but for your sample, it is intentionally over-engineered ... :) I hope you can forgive me. The ToList() at the end is needed, otherwise no action will be performed on the IEnumerable. Or you can use this approach:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    pipeline.Process(conn.Query<SomeType>("SOME SQL HERE", buffered: true), cts.Token).All(b => b)
        ? "All records processed successfully"
        : "Some records failed");
```

If you want to cancel from inside the data processing step, declare cts first:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var pipeline = Pipeline.Create<SomeType,bool>(st =>
{
    //Do something with st
    //you could even cancel from here
    if(someOtherBool)
        cts.Cancel();
    return someBool; //some bool if you succeeded or not for example
});
```

And if you don't want to declare a specific type:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var pipeline = Pipeline.Create<dynamic,bool>(d =>
{
    //Do something with data
    if(someOtherBool)
        cts.Cancel();
    return someBool; //some bool if you succeeded or not
});

using (var conn = new SqlConnection("someConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    foreach (var b in pipeline.Process(conn.Query("SOME SQL HERE", buffered: true), cts.Token))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b?"Success":"Failure");
    }
}
```

One last thing to mention is that the cts.Cancel() usually throws an exception on the inner thread, so enclose the pipeline in a try/catch if needed.

**UPDATE 2**

After reading comments from the author, I'd still opt for a combo of Dapper, PEE and Rx (pun intended).

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var pipeline = Pipeline.Create<dynamic, dynamic>(d =>
{
    //Do something with data in step 1
    if (someConditionalCheck)
        cts.Cancel();
    return d; 
}).Next<dynamic>(d =>
{
    //do something with data is step 2
    if(someConditionalCheck)
        cts.Cancel();
    return d;
});

subscription = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Subscribe(_ =>
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("someConnectionString"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (var v in pipeline.Process(conn.Query("SOME SQL HERE", buffered: true), cts.Token))
            {
                //Do something with or ignore the result
            }
        }
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        //Investigate what happened, could be error in processing 
        //or operation cancelled
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //All other exceptions
    }
});
```

Rx lets me create a neat observable which will fire every minute. I could as well devise one which fires after a period of inactivity from the previous run, I just prefer interval in this case.

PEE let me create a neat workflow, where I can specify multiple steps to be performed on one data item retrieved from the database. Having access to the CancellationTokenSource lets me cancel all the steps as soon as each step is complete, so if one record is in step 1 and another in step N, both will be cancelled as soon as their respective code blocks will completed.

Dapper is just a time server when talking to the database, period.

However, As you can tell, I am not really using Threads or Task, so am I answering the authors question here? Not really. Instead I am providing him with an alternative, which I think better fits his data processing scenario.

But if I had to choose, I'd still stick to Task Factory, as it is leaner and more convenient than managing threads yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `WaitAll` blocks the thread, which more or less defeats the purpose of doing background processes.

Comment: And you would rather indiscriminately block the thread for ten seconds while waiting for the next loop? It makes little sense to me. He should be cancelling from a separate thread, not inside the "wait loop". That's just bad code.

Comment: @Darek So then why are you not posting an answer that shows how to do it properly, instead of providing an answer that does it wrong?

Comment: Because I have no clue where `terminate` could be coming from, @Servy. If more details were provided, I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: If you can't post a quality answer then don't post an answer at all, rather than posting a bad answer advocating a solution that you well know isn't one that should be used.

Comment: Given that you have plenty of experience providing good answers, would you mind educating me what is wrong with mine, given the limited amount of information the author provided? @Servy

Comment: @Darek: I'm guessing what you mean about cancelling from a separate thread is that the *signal* for cancellation comes from a separate thread?

Comment: Indeed, @code4life. Usually it is an event in response to a user action, processing error, etc.

Comment: @Darek, ive updated question and code slightly, im on tablet so not ideal :)

Comment: @Neil, yes I saw and updated my answer. If your question is purely academic, than I and many others in this thread opt for Tasks. If you are looking for a solution to a problem you have, I think my approach provides an neat way to solve it. Hop into the C# chat channel if you have more questions.